# Catch the output from a child console batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, parent-child

When I run an exe file in CMD it opens a new console (child). I need to redirect the output of this child console to a file. With > after the command only the parent console is redirected. Also "START /B" doesn't help me, it still open a new console.

Comment: The application itself determines how it interacts with a console. If the app really wants to open its console, you may not be able to stop it. Does the app take any command-line arguments (like `--help` or `/?`)?

Comment: Yes, it takes one or more arguments.

Comment: What I mean is, does it take arguments that control where it sends output or whether or not it opens a new console window? If the app itself opens a window, it's difficult (or impossible) to stop it from doing so.

Comment: There are no arguments to control the output or the console window. So, I can't redirect to a file the output generated by the child console, am I right?